# What's the best way to import Email into SharePoint?

Tags: tools, email

I would like to import Email from Exchange into a SharePoint site/document library.

Are there any tools to do this?

What is the best way to go about this?

It would be about 18GB of data.

Comment: What's the purpose of storing it in SharePoint?

Comment: To view it in multiple locations, and to reduce the exchange mailbox size.

Comment: Correctly designed, a SP farm can be a very good alternative to internal email. For example, I used to have an extranet running on WSS 3 for customers. Each customers had a dedicated site collection, and each project made for this customer has its subweb. Discussion lists/doucment library and others lists, make us nearly stop using email. All communications, all documents, all bug report, ... was done from the WSS platform. Only "reticent" customers or non customer still was using emails, but the numbers was quite low. This is not an answer to your question, but more another way to think :=

Comment: Have you considered writing a PowerShell script to extract the data from Exchange and put it into SharePoint?

Answer (score 1):

What about configure your library for incoming emails? Maybe thats a possibility to solve your problem.

You have to install and configure the SMTP Service on your SharePoint Server. The configuration must be done in the SP central administration. When this is done you navigate to your library where you want to "import" your Emails. In the library settings is a point named "incoming email settings". In this settings you allow the library to receive e-mail, choose the email address for your library and so on. Lastly, ensure that you Accept e-mail messages from any sender is selected.

Here you can find a step by step guide for configuring  incoming email: http://sharepointgeorge.com/2010/configuring-incoming-email-sharepoint-2010/

Comment: Can you add more details regarding how configure what you propose? It will make your answer much more helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

There is an alternative to import, if you just want to make emails and attachments discovered by SharePoint. In the Search Service Application it is possible to crawl public folders of Exchange Server 2010/2007.

Reference: [Plan crawling and federation in SharePoint 2013](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219577.aspx)